# Windows 7 Run as non admin user from command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-7

I run as admin on my machine and want to run an executable as non admin user from the command prompt (without logging off).
I'm running on windows 7 64 bit OS.
Is possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you Shift + Right click on the icon to launch the Command Prompt, you'll see the option to "Run as a different user"

You can then specify a non admin account.  Anything launched from that command prompt will be executed as the user you specified.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Commandline: runas /user: programm.exe

This only works for .exe files in the Windows directory. For other programms, you need to tell Windows the correct path.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't that work for anything in the system path?

Comment: Yes, your right. Thatßs what I meant with "Windows directory" but System path is the better expression, I guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the runas command from a command window.

Start a new command window using:  runas /user: cmd

then run your command program from the new command window.